# Error using fit in sklearn for covariance estimation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, curve-fitting

I have a variable **xcin** which contains data in form of an array . I am trying to fit this data using fit() present in GraphLassoCV .

Data present in xcin :

```
[ 0.722    0.32202  0.70102  0.7414   0.18204  0.01132  0.171    0.723
  0.722    0.52605  0.70102  0.7414   0.29253  0.95     0.729    0.7414
  0.74999  0.7412   0.454    0.7414   0.15122  0.7414   0.65992  0.723
  0.70102  0.45209  0.521    0.7412   0.92412  0.01403  0.45203  0.723
  0.9303   0.454    0.74999  0.5232   0.6309   0.1712   0.7414   0.221
  0.70102  0.851    0.241    0.01122  0.749    0.749    0.24232  0.454
  0.80904  0.454    0.40106  0.74999  0.74999  0.17123  0.74999  0.7412
  0.271    0.7414   0.55204  0.7414   0.5259   0.7414   0.749    0.7414
  0.722    0.28133  0.9219   0.749    0.729    0.749    0.3311   0.45201
  0.9303   0.45201  0.722    0.6304   0.722    0.40106  0.45205  0.18109
  0.722    0.749    0.749    0.5259   0.40107  0.40106  0.36911  0.7414
  0.7412   0.74999  0.154    0.851    0.722    0.154    0.722    0.74999
  0.29253  0.729    0.7412   0.6309 ]
```

I tried using the following code :

```
xcin =np.array([df['xcin']])/100000.0
# Learn a graphical structure from the correlations
edge_model = covariance.GraphLassoCV()
X = xcin.copy().T
X /= X.std(axis=0)
edge_model.fit(X)
```

But I am getting an error on edge_model.fit() line :

```
ValueError: Found array with 1 feature(s) (shape=(100, 1)) while a minimum of 2 is required by GraphLassoCV.
```

Can someone explain how to resolve this .

I am trying to follow the approach as demonstrated here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-stock-market-py ) to generate a similar type of visualization .

Comment: sklearn tells you what the problem is. The shape of the input is wrong (100 samples with 1 feature; sklearn wants >= 2 features). But i don't understand your combination of data & algorithm here so it would be a good idea to add some more information before someone can help.

Comment: I am trying to do clustering based on industry codes . These 100 data points correspond to different types of industries which are present . I wanted to use affinity propagation because the number of clusters is not known from the beginning . What can I do in this case

Answer (score 1):

Your data is 100x1 meaning that you have 100 numbers. So this is either 100 samples of 1dim data or 1 sample of 100 dim data. Either way there is no concept of covariance matrix with such data, you need at least 2 samples and 2 dimensions. With just one dimension the only things you can compute is a variance. In particular this behaviour is commented in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/covariance/graph_lasso_.py#L576)

```
# Covariance does not make sense for a single feature
X = check_array(X, ensure_min_features=2, estimator=self)
```

Comment: I am trying to do clustering based on industry codes . These 100 data points correspond to different types of industries which are present . I wanted to use affinity propagation because the number of clusters is not known from the beginning . What can I do in this case

Comment: Ml is really not for one domensional data. Something that simple can be achieved woth simple scripts, drawing your data etc.

Answer (score 0):

use sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(2).fit_transform(X)  to make more features

Comment: Please elaborate little more about the solution you have given. Use formatting for your line of source code. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer